Girvan-Newnam with custom centrality index throws "remove_edge() must be an iterable, not int"
I want to apply Girvan-Newnam to a graph with a custom centrality index (betweenness centrality based on edge weights). I follow the documentation of the algorithm and of custom betweenness centrality and programmed this minimal reproducible example:
import math
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import itertools

proximity = np.random.random_integers(1, 100, (10, 10))


def build_graph(proximity):

    G = nx.Graph()

    for i in range(proximity.shape[0]):
        G.add_node(i)
        for j in range(i):
            G.add_edge(i, j, weight=math.exp(-proximity[i, j]))

    return G


def most_central_edge(G, weight="weight"):
    centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight=weight)
    #print(centrality)
    return max(centrality, key=centrality.get)


G = build_graph(proximity[:100, :100])
comp = nx.community.girvan_newman(G, most_valuable_edge=most_central_edge)

print(tuple(sorted(c) for c in next(comp)))

It throws this error:
TypeError: networkx.classes.graph.Graph.remove_edge() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

How can I apply Girvan-Newnam with weighted betweenness centrality?

nx.community.girvan_newman requires as parameter for most_valuable_edge a function that outputs an edge:

most_valuable_edge: function
Function that takes a graph as input and outputs an edge. The edge returned by this function will be recomputed and removed at each iteration of the algorithm.
If not specified, the edge with the highest networkx.edge_betweenness_centrality() will be used.

But your most_central_edge function outputs a node:
def most_central_edge(G, weight="weight"):
    centrality = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, weight=weight)
    return max(centrality, key=centrality.get)

most_central_edge(G, weight="weight")
# 3

Althougth I don't know your exact logic, you should probably use edge_betweenness_centrality:
def most_central_edge(G, weight="weight"):
    centrality = nx.edge_betweenness_centrality(G, weight=weight)
    return max(centrality, key=centrality.get)

G = build_graph(proximity[:100, :100])
comp = nx.community.girvan_newman(G, most_valuable_edge=most_central_edge)

print(tuple(sorted(c) for c in next(comp)))
# ([0, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 7, 8, 9])

